# Custom TableViewCell contents invisible on ios9 xcode7

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

iOS9 upgrade seem to have broken all my custom tableviewcell. They only show tableviewcell with the right height, but all the elements inside are missing.

The layout worked perfectly on iOS 8 and iOS 7 devices.

Here's a screenshot of my Storyboard
[image: Storyboard with a custom tableviewcell dummycell with a label]

Yet when it comes on the device, only background color shows up.

[image: It shows only the content view]

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DummyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DummyCell
    cell.label.text = "DummyLabel"
    return cell
}
```

Has anyone faced similar issue with ios 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue. Check your constraints in your Storyboard. In our case some configurations did not work on iOS 9.

Comment: extra weird for me because my cells would populate correctly on initial load, but any inserted rows were empty (even if I reloadData). thanks!!

Comment: I am having this issue too, is it only with storyboards? I'm going to try to layout the whole view controller in code now and see if that fixes because my constraints seem fine in the storyboard.