# Custom TableViewCell contents invisible on iOS9 (Xcode7)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

since the upgrade to Xcode 7 & testing my app with iOS9, the contents of some custom cells have become invisible at runtime. There's an emphasis on 'some' here, as this affects only 2 out of 6 table views, all of which reside in different view controllers.

A similar problem was encountered here, but the answer ("check constraints") does not work for me:
[Custom TableViewCell contents invisible on ios9 xcode7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506453/custom-tableviewcell-contents-invisible-on-ios9-xcode7)

The cell that makes trouble is a large placeholder that is displayed when no data is available to be presented in the table.
It only contains a UILabel which is centered by two constraints.

[image: Click to see the cell]

The cell, as well as other custom cells not shown in the picture, are visible at runtime. However, not their contents.

In other view controllers of the same app, the exact same custom cell (same design, same class, same reuse identifier...) work as they should.
However, not in this VC.

Before the upgrade to Xcode 7 and testing on iOS9, the cell's content was visible also in this VC. 
I haven't changed anything in IB or the code and double-checked everything a couple times. It's crazy and I am desperately looking for help :-)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I figured out the answer:

In iOS 8.4, the label is installed in the view hierarchy, whereas it isn't in iOS 9.2 according to XCode's view debugger. 
The size class for the label is Regular/Regular, which should suffice for iPad.
When I add the size class Any/Any for the label, it will install correctly.

This is clearly a bug which has been confirmed to my by Apple, but not acted upon yet.

Comment: Make sure you add Any/Any in addition to other size classes, or just design the UI in Any/Any and then add additional size classes if needed.